# Upload Chart from Excel file (which downloads data from SharePoint) to SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, external

I am trying to use live charts that I created in Excel file in my SharePoint page. My Excel downloads data from my SharePoint survey and refreshes data every minute. I am trying to make a live display of my survey results. I download data from SharePoint by SharePoint List query and it works well. I put my Excel charts on my SharePoint page by Web Part -> Business Data -> Excel Web Access. The chart is displayed but when I try to refresh it SharePoint drops error: **We were unable to refresh one or more data connections in this workbook.**

Is it possible to do in SharePoint live chart from excel downloading data from SharePoint, and if yes then how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this as well and have received the same error.  This is a known error for Sharepoint On Premise 2010.  If you have Sharepoint Online, recommend using PowerBI instead of Excel.

What I have done for a workaround is created a VBScript that refreshes the Excel file that hosts the chart.  I save the Excel file in Sharepoint Assets folder and then create a Task Scheduler to run the VBScript for the desired time increments.  The Task Scheduler / VBScript could be replaced by creating a workflow within Sharepoint but you need to use Sharepoint Designer.  Here is the VBScript code I use:

```
set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Application.DisplayAlerts=False
set wb = xl.WorkBooks.open("location of excel file goes here")
WScript.Sleep 1000
xl.ActiveWorkbook.LockServerFile (only use if location is in Sharepoint to turn off edit mode)
wb.RefreshAll
wb.Save
xl.Application.DisplayAlerts=True
wb.Close
xl.Quit
```

Another option is to create an Excel macro file that refreshes the Excel file hosting the chart upon opening.  Create a link to the Excel macro file within your Sharepoint site that says "Refresh Data".  Then when individuals click on "Refresh Data" link, the Excel Macro file is opened, refreshes the Excel File that hosts the chart.  Sloppy but works as well.